# How to restore corrupted database file in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I formatted my System (C:)in which my database files are stored unfortunately my database backup have lost.I used recovering tools to recover my database files as dump file.when i tried to restore my dump file its displaying error as i mentioned below,

```
 18:00:34 Restoring E:\pos1.sql
```

Running: mysql.exe --defaults-file="c:\users\ashfaq\appdata\local\temp\tmpdi5lll.cnf"  --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments < "E:\pos1.sql"
ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: ''.

Operation failed with exitcode 1
18:00:36 Import of E:\pos1.sql has finished with 1 errors

any help will be appreciated...

Comment: and what is the error? i am affraid, your sql file has damaged.

Comment: Don't you want to show the actual SQL query? Btw, what tools did you use?